# Django rest multiple nested Related

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, model

I have 3 table `Province`, `Commune` and `District` that link to each other.

```
Province hasMany District
District hasMany Commune
```

When vist my api url `api/v1/province/` i got data like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name_eng": "Banteay Meanchey",
        "name_kh": "បន្ទាយមានជ័យ",
        "district": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name_eng": "Mongkol Borei",
                "name_kh": "មង្គលបុរី",
                "province": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name_eng": "Malay",
                "name_kh": "មា៉ឡៃ",
                "province": 1
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I want to make it nested multiple like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name_eng": "Banteay Meanchey",
        "name_kh": "បន្ទាយមានជ័យ",
        "district": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name_eng": "Mongkol Borei",
                "name_kh": "មង្គលបុរី",
                "province": 1
               "commune": [
                  "id": 1,
                  "name_eng": "Mongkol Borei",
                  "name_kh": "មង្គលបុរី",
               ]
            },       
        ]
    },
```

Is it Possible to do so???
**`My Model`**

```
class Province(models.Model):
    name_eng = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name_kh = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class District(models.Model):
    province = models.ForeignKey(
        Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="district")
    name_eng = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name_kh = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Commune(models.Model):
    district = models.ForeignKey(
        District, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="commune")
    name_eng = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name_kh = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**`My Serializer`**

```
class ProvinceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # commune = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Province
        fields = ['id', 'name_eng', 'name_kh', 'district']
        depth = 1


class DistrictSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = District

        fields = ['id', 'name_eng', 'name_kh', 'commune']
        # fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1


class CommuneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Commune
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = ['id', 'name_eng', 'name_kh', 'district']
        depth = 1
```

I'll appreciate of all ur help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible and django designed to do thing such this.
for making this model / serializer you should use nested relationship (according to DRF [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/))

you should change your serializer.py to this:

```
class CommuneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Commune
        fields = ['id', 'name_eng', 'name_kh']
        depth = 1


class DistrictSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    commune = CommuneSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = District
        fields = ['id', 'name_eng', 'name_kh', 'commune']
        depth = 1


class ProvinceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    district = DistrictSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Province
        fields = ['id', 'name_eng', 'name_kh', 'district']
        depth = 1
```